# is there any good way to limit one time code change size on git/gerrit

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gerrit

we have process to limit one code inspection/commit size, and would like to build in tool to check and block all commit over limit.
based on git/gerrit plugin & google search,  did not see any existing solution for such limitation. is there any practice or suggestion to buildup such limitation on git/gerrit.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Gerrit has such [option](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#_maximum_git_object_size_limit).

It can be configured globally by [receive.maxObjectSizeLimit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#receive.maxObjectSizeLimit).

For a specific project, you can find `Maximum Git object size limit:` on the `General` page of the project.

Update:

If you want to check the number of changed lines in Gerrit, I'd recommend you Gerrit hook `ref-update`. It works a bit like Git hook `update`. The hook receives the old commit and the new commit via `--oldrev <sha1> --newrev <sha1>`. The parameter list may vary in different versions of Gerrit. Please refer to the document of your Gerrit for details. If the hook exits with a non-zero value, the push will be rejected.

Sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while test $# != 0
do
  case $1 in
  --oldrev)
      shift
      oldrev=$1
  ;;
  --newrev)
      shift
      newrev=$1
  ;;
  esac
  shift
done

if [[ "${newrev}" = ${z40} ]];then
    # Handle delete
    # Do something here

else
    if [[ "${oldrev}" = ${z40} ]];then
        # New branch
        # Do something here

    else
        # Update existing branch, check new commits
        newcommits=$(git log --pretty=%H ${oldrev}..${newrev})
        for commit in ${newcommits};do
            shortstat=$(git show ${commit} --pretty="" --shortstat)
            # Parse shortstat to get the numbers of deletions and insertions
            # if the number is big enough, print error message and exit with a non-zero value, 
            # so that git-push will be rejected

        done
    fi
fi
exit 0
```

If you want to check it in the local repository, I'd suggest the Git hook `pre-commit`.

Sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash

shortstat=$(git diff --cached --shortstat)
# parse shortstat to get the numbers of deletions and insertions
# if the number is big enough, print error message and exit with a non-zero value, 
# so that git-commit will fail
```

The Gerrit hook is more reliable because it's always invoked by every new commit that's to be reviewed, but it may affect the performance of the Gerrit service. The Git hook may be bypassed purposely or unexpectedly but it runs locally. Besides, I don't consider binary files in the samples. Their deletions and insertions cannot reflect the real delta size.

Comment: ElpieKay, thanks for your suggestion. But we would like to check number of line code change, not the object size.  Looks maxObjectSizeLimit is used to specify the object file size, not the code change delta size. sorry i did not make it clear.

Comment: @arden I updated the answer to offer two possible solutions.